# How to Resolve Dash Bootstrap No_Gutter Type Error

Tags: python, plotly-dash

When I run this code, I get an error message saying "Error: The `dash_bootstrap_components.Row` component (version 1.0.2) received an unexpected keyword argument: `no_gutters`
Allowed arguments: align, children, className, class_name, id, justify, key, loading_state, style"

I believe it's because of the dash bootstrap version I use. How do I modify my code to make it work?

```
app.layout = dbc.Container([

    dbc.Row(
        dbc.Col(html.H1("My Dashboard",
                        className='text-center'),
                width=12)
    ),

    dbc.Row([

        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Dropdown(id='my-dpdn', multi=False, value='A',
                         options=[{'label':x, 'value':x}
                                  for x in sorted(df['Value'].unique())],
                         ),
            dcc.Graph(id='line-fig', figure={})
        ],# width={'size':5, 'offset':1, 'order':1},
           xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=5, xl=5
        ),

        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Dropdown(id='my-dpdn2', multi=True, value=['B','C'],
                         options=[{'label':x, 'value':x}
                                  for x in sorted(df['Value'].unique())],
                         ),
            dcc.Graph(id='line-fig2', figure={})
        ], #width={'size':5, 'offset':0, 'order':2},
           xs=12, sm=12, md=12, lg=5, xl=5
        ),

    ], no_gutters=True, justify='start')


], fluid=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Version 1.0 for Dash-bootstrap-components, the `no_gutters` attribute for the Row component has been deprecated. You are probably using code from a version <= 0.13, read this [migration guide](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/migration-guide/) for the full details of the changes.

You have a couple of options here:

1. Reading that migration guide will suggest the new way of removing gutters under the heading *Row without 'gutters'*

> Dropped no_gutters prop. Use gutter modifier classes instead. See the [docs](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/) for examples.

2- You can revert your dash-bootstrap-components library back to 0.13 (eg. `pip install dash-bootstrap-components==0.13`), but this is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, how to make change?  I have this:              html.A(
                dbc.Row(
                    [dbc.Col(html.Img(src="assets/dark_logo.png", height="20px"))],
                    align="center",
                    no_gutters=True,  Do I just remove no_gutters=True? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can just switch the

```
no_gutters=True
```

For

```
className="g-0"
```

Comment: Does this add anything that the existing answer doesn't explain?